# Extra added field value to be sent in post method

Tags: php, javascript, html

After adding the extra field using javascript, the extra field values are not being sent by post method in php. Here in the code adding the basic 5 fields, rest are the extra fields that user can add if necessary

The code is as follows:

```
  <script language="javascript">
  var i = 11;
  function changeIt()
  {

  my_div.innerHTML = my_div.innerHTML +"<tr><td> <input id='item"+i+"' name='item"+i+"' type='text' maxlength='255' value=''/></td><td><input id='kgorp"+i+"' name='kgorp"+i+"' type='text' maxlength='3' value=''/></td><br/></tr>";
  i++;
  }
  </script>
  <body>
     Please enther the grocery items
   <table>
  <tr>
  <th> Item name</th><th> kg/No of packet</th>
  </tr>
  <form  method="post" action="gl.php">
<tr> <td><input id="item1" name="item1" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/></td><td><input id="kgorp1" name="kgorp1" type="text" maxlength="3" value=""/></td></tr>
<tr> <td><input id="item2" name="item2" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/></td><td><input id="kgorp2" name="kgorp2" type="text" maxlength="3" value=""/></td></tr>
<tr> <td> <input id="item3" name="item3" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/></td><td><input id="kgorp3" name="kgorp3" type="text" maxlength="3" value=""/></td></tr>
<tr> <td> <input id="item4" name="item4" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/></td><td><input id="kgorp4" name="kgorp4" type="text" maxlength="3" value=""/></td></tr>
<tr> <td> <input id="item5" name="item5" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/></td><td><input id="kgorp5" name="kgorp5" type="text" maxlength="3" value=""/></td></tr>
<tr id="my_div"></tr>
<tr> <td><input id="saveForm" type="submit" value="Submit List" /></td><td><input id="addtxt" type="button" name="addtxt" value="Add more items" onClick="changeIt()" /></td> </tr>
</form>
   </table>
   </body>
```

The php code for retrieving the data sent via post method,

```
$i=1;
foreach ($_POST as $param_value) {
  if ( empty( $param_value ) ) { 

  } else {
    echo "<td>$param_value</td>";
    if ( ( $i % 2 ) == 0 ) {
      echo "</tr> <tr>";
    }//echo $i;
  }
  $i++;
}
```

Comment: add name attribute to your `<form>` tag

Comment: @Prabu i dont know how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with how your form tag is placed and parsed in the HTML DOM.
Put the form tag higher in the document, after the  tag.

```
<body>
  Please enther the grocery items
  <form method="post" action="gl.php">
```

and then change the javascript to this:

```
function changeIt()
{
    var child = document.createElement('td');
    child.innerHTML = "<input id='item"+i+"' name='item"+i+"' type='text' maxlength='255' value=''/><input id='kgorp"+i+"' name='kgorp"+i+"' type='text' maxlength='3' value=''/>";
    document.getElementById("my_div").appendChild(child);
    i++;
}
```

What you should get when you do a print_r($_POST) is:

```
Array ( [item1] => [kgorp1] => [item2] => [kgorp2] => [item3] => [kgorp3] => [item4] => [kgorp4] => [item5] => [kgorp5] => [item6] => [kgorp6] => [item7] => [kgorp7] => [item8] => [kgorp8] => [item9] => [kgorp9] => [item10] => [kgorp10] => [item11] => [kgorp11] => )
```

A better solution is to get rid of the table and tr/td tags and work with divs/spans for the form (its a lot nicer way to code, honestly :) )

Comment: yes i do see the values in the extra added items and the php goes pick up the fields up to 10

Comment: You are indeed generating valid form elements. Now can you show me some sample PHP code that reads the $_POST variables?

Comment: <?php
      $i=1;
      foreach ($_POST as $param_value) {

 if(empty($param_value))
 {

 }
 else
 {
        echo "<td>$param_value</td>";
 
 
 if( ($i % 2) == 0)
 {
   echo "</tr> <tr>";
 }
 }
 $i++;

      }
      ?>

Comment: can you do a "print_r($_POST);" at the top of the php code to see the full post array?

Comment: Array ( [item1] => [kgorp1] => [item2] => [kgorp2] => [item3] => [kgorp3] => [item4] => [kgorp4] => [item5] => [kgorp5] => [item6] => dasd [kgorp6] => 569 [item7] => [kgorp7] => [item8] => [kgorp8] => [item9] => [kgorp9] => [item10] => [kgorp10] => )

Comment: item11 and kgorp is not being posted

Comment: Have a look at my modified solution above, it works on my computer

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0;i<=11;i++) {
    document.getElementById("my_div").innerHTML = document.getElementById("my_div").innerHTML +"<tr>
    <td> <input id='item"+i+"' name='item"+i+"' type='text' maxlength='255' value=''/></td>
    <td><input id='kgorp"+i+"' name='kgorp"+i+"' type='text' maxlength='3' value=''/></td>
    <br/>
    </tr>";
 }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qn3kT/)

Comment: no actually this will not work because, i want the script variable to start with number 11 and continue numbering and send these extra fields via form post method

Comment: Please check the demo link it will show the result and exact scripts

Comment: yes i saw the demo and added the link for php c the out put its still empty with input in extra fields entry

Comment: you need the value for the textboxes like 11,12,13 etc ? if yes check this link http://jsfiddle.net/qn3kT/3/

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where the my_div variable is initialized.
You could do, in the beginning of your changeIt function:

```
var my_div = document.getElementById('my_div')
```

Then another problem: don't name this variable my_div while it's actually a tr tag.

And further: in this tr tag, your changeIt function will include HTML containing another tr, so you'll end up with bad HTML. A suggestion: do not use tables but instead, div or li tags for such a listing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using it in a function, simply put it inline inside your form in the following manner,

```
document.write('<input type="hidden" name="whatever" value="'+i+'">');
```

and make the adjustments necessary according to what you need.

Comment: this will take to a new page with extra fields